# Disable the ServiceBrokerExceptionHandler of the Open Service Broker API

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I implemented the Open Service Broker API with Spring 2.0. Currently, every exception is caught by the `ServiceBrokerExceptionHandler`:

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = ServiceBrokerRestController.class)
@ResponseBody
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 10)
public class ServiceBrokerExceptionHandler { ... }
```

This handler propagates every internal exception to the user. Recently, I saw an EclipseLink exception thrown to the user exposing table structures of my database. I would like to overwrite or fully disable the `ServiceBrokerExceptionHandler`. I tried implementing my own exception handler with a higher `@Order` of the `ServiceBrokerExceptionHandler`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE -10)
@ResponseBody
public static class MyOwnExceptionHandler extends ServiceBrokerExceptionHandler { ... }
```

While the exception handler works for "normal" REST calls it does not for calls to the OSB API. Is there a way to overwrite/disable the built-in ServiceBrokerExceptionHandler`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made kind of a stupid mistake. `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` is defined as `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. So if I subtract the value -10 in `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE -10)` the lowest possible integer will be exceeded. While this is a wrong usage by me, I wonder what the default order is, if the user/developer handles the order wrong. For now, it's good enough for me to set the order to a valid number:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 10)
@ResponseBody
public static class MyOwnExceptionHandler extends ServiceBrokerExceptionHandler { ... }
```

Comment: I wonder how did you make it work, I tried the exact same thing and is ignoring my ControllerAdvice. And also, your class cannot be static, that's a compilation error